# Is there a way to build a recipient list from another table in directmail in typo3 6.1?

Tags: email, typo3, newsletter

I'm currently upgrading TV sites to 6.1 and tasked to implement a newsletter functionality within typo3. I was using the newsletter extension in 4.7 but the extension bugged on the scheduler. I would love to have the simplicity of building the recipient list (just like in the [newsletter extension](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-newsletter)) from a table of my choice as I already have a powermail subscription working. This way I could build the list collected via powermail.

Comment: A tad late, but Newsletter extension was updated to support TYPO3 6.1 - 7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a somewhat hidden feature in direct_mail called "Special query".
In the recipient list module, you have to click the name of a recipient group - NOT the edit icon.
This will guide you to a full-fledged editor for queries out of which you can dynamically build your recipient lists on the fly.

Comment: Well I saw that option in the manual but nothing about clicking usergroups. Thanks I'll try your option

Comment: Just found: http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/powermail/2.0.0/view/1/48/ which means rather than retrieve the emails from the powermail table, I can get powermail to save the email address directly to tt_address and not bother with the special query.

Comment: Probably it would be best to combine the two functionalities, so you can e.g. select tt_address records by category or pid

Comment: brilliant! Just what I was looking for.